# Next Button moves only one record up, next click doesn't work (C#)

Tags: c#

I have be below code to navigate through records by selecting the next records id using the current id in lblID.text. But when I click on the next button for the first time it works and moves to the next id but the second and subsequent clicks don't work. I need help (below is the code)

```
protected void btnNext_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            int currentrowID = Convert.ToInt32(lblID.Text);
            SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(connection);
            string commandtext = "SELECT TOP 1 * FROM Outwards WHERE id > @currentrowID ORDER BY id";
            SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(commandtext, con);
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@currentrowID", currentrowID);
            con.Open();
            SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();

            while (reader.Read())
            {
                lblID.Text = reader["id"].ToString();
                lblPayerBankRoutNo.Text = reader["PayorBankRoutNo"].ToString();
                lblAccountNumber.Text = reader["AccountNo"].ToString();
                lblTransCode.Text = reader["TransCode"].ToString();
                lblAmount.Text = reader["Amount"].ToString();

                //showing front image
                byte[] frontimagebyte = (byte[])reader["FImage"];
                RadBinaryImage1.ImageUrl = "data:image;base64," + Convert.ToBase64String(frontimagebyte);

                //showing front image
                byte[] rearimagebyte = (byte[])reader["RImage"];
                RadBinaryImage2.ImageUrl = "data:image;base64," + Convert.ToBase64String(rearimagebyte);
            }

            reader.Close();
            con.Close();
        }
```

Comment: How do you update your currentrowID?

Comment: Are you looking for *pagination*? `SELECT * FROM ... ORDER BY id OFFSET 10 /* put correct value here */ ROWS FETCH NEXT 1 ROWS ONLY` see https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg699618.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

Comment: @andreasnico inside the while loop: `lblID.Text = reader["id"].ToString();`

Comment: @MarsoftGh is your lable updating after `btnNext_Click`?

Comment: You can break this problem down by setting a breakpoint on the first line and stepping through the code to see if it does what you expect. Does currentrowID get set to the value you expect? Do you get any rows back from the query? Is the label set to the new value? etc.. It's very hard to fix code just by looking at it.

Comment: Thanks @andreasnico, thats my problem. I set a break point on the frist line and realized that on first click the label updates to the next row ID. but on the next click I realize the value of currentRowID is the initial value of the lable not the new lable value.

Comment: Good the hear you fixed it :)